# creating database tables and records from user input

Tags: java, user-input

I'd like to create a workflow management tool with Java that allows different users to dynamically create their own database tables and records at runtime from a swing Gui client on the fly based on their need. Is there a sane way of realising this? I'd appreciate some pointers in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there is a sane way of realizing this. No, we're not going to design a system for you.

Comment: So basically, you want to work with databases, using JAVA. Google is your friend.

Comment: What have you tried, what technologies do you know and what problems have you encountered? At least a minimal effort of research is expected before asking questions here.

Answer (score 0):

You can create tables on the fly using simple "CREATE table" SQL commands using JDBC.
Sometimes the schema of the database might be locked in production where creation of new objects is not permitted, if you have permission to create tables in the database then there is nothing stopping you from creating tables dynamically.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idead to grant 'create table' privileges (and probably also 'drop table') to a runtime database user in a productive environment.

Comment: so that means you don't approve of any tool to manage databases? what does it matter if the user is using a swing ui or the command line client?